# Why does an Android activity continue running until the end of the method even after startActivity() was fired?

Tags: android, android-activity

I wrote the enclosed code for Android to check the following scenario:

1. Activity #1 invokes activity #2, through startActivity(intent) (in this case this is triggred by clicking a button in the UI).
2. Activity #2 is aborted by the user (by pressing the "return" button).

I wanted to know whether activity #1 will continue running from the point where it ended (i.e. right after startActivity) or will it ignore any code after startActivity to the end of the method and wait for further events.

To my great surprise I discovered that the activity #1 continued running "in the background" until the end of the method, even after activity #2 was launched...
I have added some delay but that didn't change anything.
Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Thanks

Yossi

```
public void Test2Intents(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(i);
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After 1st Intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent i2 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com"));
    startActivity(i2);  
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After 2nd Intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Activity is not finished until closed by calling finish().

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Activity#1 added in BackStack - see this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Mirat, I read through the article on Backstack and it does not answer my question. In the article it says "When the current activity starts another, the new activity is pushed on the top of the stack and takes focus. The previous activity remains in the stack, but is stopped." but it seems that the initial activity is not really stopped but keeps on running until the end of the method. Can anyone explain why this is happening?